# Android Licensing - Extras for APK Expansion are missing

Tags: android, apk, android-lvl, apk-expansion-files

After many hours of reading through Google's docs, it is obvious that implementing APK expansion download with the whole licensing mechanism takes 60% of my app's code. And yes, I really need to have expansion files (over 100MB)

So, what I did was read through all of those docs about APK expansions, implement them one by one, and test. Everything seems to be working now, until I get to fetching URLs for those expansion files.

The problem I am facing (and I've checked key, dev account, UUID and other obvious stuff) - licensing passes as LICENSED, but no extras are received in the licensing policy response. More specifically, method `com.google.android.vending.licensing.APKExpansionPolicy#processServerResponse()` has a parameter called `rawData` which has a field `extras` inside. In my test case, that `extras` is always empty.

Now, I tried to download the app through the beta channel (no production apk is available on the store), no expansion files were downloaded even then! I am guessing that my setup is somehow wrong on the Google Play store, but I have no clue what exactly am I missing.. This has become a very painful process for a simple app as this one, implementing dozens of methods and learning tons of APIs just to be able to host one zip file somewhere.. I could have hosted that file myself and implemented the download mechanism ages ago..

Comment: Oh, right, forgot to say that I waited 24 hours to give Google some time for the apk/files upload..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I uploaded the newest version of the app on Google Play, and used **the same version** for testing. Although expansion files were named main.2.package.name.obb (with version 2), I tested with version 4 and everything worked. You should definitely hard-code the OBB version and use it in all later versions.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this and it drove me crazy. The reason in my case was that the `android:versionCode="XX"`was a later version than the version uploaded to the app store.

So when my app queried the play store, the extras were missing because it didn't recognize the version of my app. Make sure that the version Code in your app is the same as the latest one in the `APK` section of the developer console and you should be good to go.

I think this is alluded to in the answers above but not clearly stated.